# How to make the android app fit all Screen Sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have a customized application , i install the app for select users . My application has separate drawable for each sizes (no problems with the drawables) , but my textViews and other content sizes does not change as per screen size . i have dimens values and i use only these 3 values across my 60 layouts, but Each time i install the app in client device, i change to values in dimens.xml according to the device inches and then build multiple apks for multiple screen size.
How do i solve this problem and make app fit all screen sizes ?

My dimens.xml

````
    < // screen 6 inch <dimen name="radio_button_text_size" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">13dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="title_size" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">13dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="value_size" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">15dp</dimen>
-->```

"'//screen 6+ inches
       <dimen name="radio_button_text_size" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">15dp</dimen>
       <dimen name="title_size" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">17dp</dimen>
       <dimen name="value_size" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">18dp</dimen>
       "'

    <!-- // screen 5inch
        <dimen name="radio_button_text_size" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">7dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="title_size" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">9dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="value_size" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">11dp</dimen>
     -->
````

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well a while back. I'm assuming you're using padding to position your views. Instead, you're gonna want to use a constraint layout and then use "horizontal bias" and "vertical bias" (the little scroll bars under the "Constraint Layout" section of the design view) to position your views. This will look the same on most screen sizes. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply .. I will do that for view position , but how do i solve the textView text size issue on various screens ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was just researching it and it looks like (https://medium.com/@kamranramzan098/supporting-adjusting-text-size-on-different-screen-sizes-in-android-a6ea82a219f5) this website has what you're looking for. Hope this helps!